# How to apply rigid foam insulation to foundation with epoxy plugs?

Tags: insulation, foundation, epoxy

The previous owners of our home did a foundation repair to fix two large cracks about 10 years ago (it is covered by a lifetime warranty). The repair was very successful, but the epoxy plugs remain.

In an effort to improve the efficiency of the home, I want to apply rigid foam (xps - 2" on walls, 1" on floors). I am left scratching my head however on how to do this on the wall with the epoxy plugs. I've included a picture below of the plugs for reference.

The best option I can think of is to strap the was with 2x2's or 2x3's first. Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with epoxy repairs, but I'd guess that those holes were drilled to allow material injection and the plugs merely retained epoxy while it cured.

> **Can I remove the injection ports after the completed repair?**
>   Yes, but first wait 24 hours to allow the LCR injection resin to harden and fully cure. A hammer and chisel will easily remove the injection ports, and the crack sealer can be sanded, ground off or painted.
>
> https://www.polygem.com/lcr-faqs-frequently-asked-questions

I'd grab them with a big ol' pliers and bend them back and forth a few times, breaking them off. A recipro-saw with a fine-toothed blade would also work.

Otherwise, if they're not too long, just press your foam onto them. A little persuasion and you can forget they were ever there. The lost insulation value is trivial.

Comment: Regarding the latter point. Are you sure? Some of the plugs are almost 2" long.

Comment: Probably not, then.